# Delete All Tables With Dates By Date

Tags: sql-server

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603817/delete-records-based-on-dates) on SO because it's similar.

I'm working on a way to delete a range of dates from all tables with date values in a database (purpose for building mini-devs).  I built a script that allows the user to pass in begin, end and database values, but am running into issues with dynamic sql.  For instance, when removing records between certain dates, I get an operand clash.  The below shows an over simplified example of this:

```
DECLARE @b DATE, @e DATE, @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @b = '2012-07-01'
SET @e = '2014-01-25'


SET @cmd = 'DELETE FROM DateTable
WHERE ValueDate BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@b,121) + ' AND ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@E,121)

EXEC sp_executesql @cmd
```

The error is `Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int`.  I tried doing an inner `CAST` within the dynamic sql since the error indicates that the `ValueDate` becomes and `INT`:

```
-- Only the WHERE clause changed:
WHERE ValueDate BETWEEN CAST(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@b,121) + ' AS DATE) AND CAST(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@E,121) + ' AS DATE)'
```

The error this time is `Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed`.  Finally I tried playing with some other formats ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)).  In a nutshell, I want to do exactly what the SO user was trying to accomplish, but be able to do it across multiple tables ([I even searched for a script](https://www.google.com/search?q=tsql%20remove%20date%20values%20in%20a%20database%20from%20tables%20with%20dates&oq=tsql%20remove%20date%20values%20in%20a%20database%20from%20tables%20with%20dates&aqs=chrome..69i57.9005j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=sql%20server%20remove%20date%20values%20in%20a%20database%20from%20tables%20with%20dates) as I doubt I'm the first person to want this).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should try printing your commands when they yield errors. If you issued this instead of executing it:

```
PRINT @cmd;
```

You would see that this:

```
WHERE ValueDate BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@b,121) + ' AND ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@E,121)
```

Yields this:

```
WHERE ValueDate BETWEEN 2012-07-01 AND 2014-01-25
```

Which, since those look to SQL Server like three integers with a couple of subtraction operators, becomes:

```
WHERE ValueDate BETWEEN 2004 AND 1988
```

Which isn't even a valid `BETWEEN` operation, even if it *could* translate those to dates.

What you *should* be doing is passing these as proper parameters, e.g.

```
SET @cmd = 'DELETE FROM dbo.DateTable -- always use SCHEMA prefix
 WHERE ValueDate BETWEEN @b AND @e;';

EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@b DATE, @e DATE', @b, @e;
```

If any of these columns are `DATETIME`, not `DATE`, you really should not be using `BETWEEN` at all. Instead:

```
WHERE ValueDate >= @b AND ValueDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @e);
```

Please read:

- https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length
- https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix
- https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common
- https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

As for the overall requirement of repeating this query against all date columns in the database, here is how I would do it (I've looked at the SO question you reference, and it just shows how to do this for one table):

```
DECLARE @b DATE = '2012-07-01', @e DATE = '2014-01-25', 
        @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
DELETE ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) 
 + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + '
  WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' >= @b
  AND ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @e);'
 FROM sys.tables AS t
 INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
 ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
 INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
 ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
 WHERE c.system_type_id IN (40,42,43,58,61);
       -- or just = 40 if you're only interested in DATE columns

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@b DATE, @e DATE', @b, @e;
```

Comment: Thank you; I tend to forget how useful `PRINT` is.

Comment: Anytime, any language, when there is generated execution code it's wise to always see what the final "code" is.  +1 great approach, Aaron.